# Unable to Request a WCSLayer - removeQueryParameters()

Tags: request, geoserver, arcgis-js-api, wcs

I am having difficulty requesting a WCSLayer from a Geoserver (version 2.17) using Javascript API (version 4.17).  I have the following code to send the request:

```
var layer = new WCSLayer({
url: "http://localhost:8083/geoserver/ows?service=wcs&version=1.1.1&request=GetCoverage&IDENTIFIER=datastore:example",
version: "1.1.1",
opacity: 0.5
});
```

And then the following ERROR message:

> [esri.layers.mixins.ImageryTileMixin] removeQueryParameters() Url
> query parameters are not supported, the following parameters have been
> removed: service, version, request, IDENTIFIER

For whatever reason, I can send in a request for a WMSLayer and it works just fine with the parameters in place. For example, if run a script with a WMSLayer request using the following:

```
http://localhost:8083/geoserver/datastore/wms?service=WMS
```

The "service" parameter is not removed and the WMS is properly added to the application. Anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you try removing the parameters from the url?

Comment: You probably need some combination of constructor options and the special option [`customParameters`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-WCSLayer.html#customParameters)....I'm not sure what the combo is, but esri like to manage the params themselves, as opposed to having you manually write it out.  I'm sure some careful combo of constructor options and `customParameters` will get you what you want